# Dimension of the linear space $\{\nabla f : \Delta f=0 \text{ and } f=const \text{ on each c.c. of the boundary} \}$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider a bounded Lischitz domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the boundary $\partial \Omega$ of $\Omega$ and write it explicitely as a disjoint union of its connected compontens (c.c.):
$$\partial \Omega = \bigsqcup_{i=1}^s \Gamma_i.$$
A first question : is the hypothesis of $\Omega$ being bounded and Lipschitz enough to ensure $s<\infty$? If not, what should one assume about $\Omega$ so that $s$ is finite?

Now consider the following linear space
$$X= \{\nabla f : f \in H^1(\Omega)\cap\Delta(\Omega),\ \Delta f=0,\ f\rvert_{\Gamma_i} \text{ is constant}\}$$
where the constant may differ from one connected component of the boundary to the other (meaning that $f$ is not constant on the whole $\partial\Omega$, but only when restricted to each c.c.).
How can I prove that $\mathrm{dim}X= s-1$?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: If $\Omega$ is bounded and Lipschitz then I believe $\partial \Omega$ is compact and locally connected, which implies that it has finitely many connected components. Also, you may want to require that $\Omega$ be connected for the dimension formula. Using the rank theorem, it’s enough to show existence and uniqueness of a harmonic function $f$ on $\Omega$ with fixed constant value on each $\Gamma_i$. Uniqueness might simply follow from elliptic regularity and maximum principle. I can’t remember the statements as far as existence is concerned.

Comment: @Mindlack Thank you for your answer. Could you elaborate a bit more the part abour the rank theorem, which would imply the didmensional formula? I still struggle to see it.

Comment: There is a linear surjection $g\in \{f \in H^1(\Omega),\, \Delta f=0,f_{|\Gamma_i}\text{ constant}\} \longmapsto \nabla g$ with kernel of rank $1$ (the constant functions). Now, assuming existence and uniqueness as in my previous comment, there is an isomorphism from the source space to $\mathbb{K}^s$ given by $g \longmapsto (g_{|\Gamma_i})_i$.

Comment: ah I see, thank you again. One small note: the dimension of the kernel is rank 1 only if $\Omega$ is connected, right? In the general case the rank should be equal to the #c.c. of $\Omega$, or am I wrong? Maybe I should edit the question setting $\Omega$ as bounded domain.

Comment: Oops, yes, you’re right, my argument needs the connectedness of $\Omega$.

Comment: I see now that actually you pointed out the problem about connectedness in your first comment. Anyway, I just wanted to finally ask you if you know a reference where to see in details the existence and uniqueness of a harmonic function with constant values on the boundary.  P.S. if you want you can write an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I think Evans’ *PDE* should cover what you want, but I’m not entirely sure.